# Pandas - Subtracting datetime columns from each other based on values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 3 datetime columns: shipment_created_date, artist_eta, and actual_delivery_date_if_known. That third column has very few values in it.

I'm wanting to subtract the shipment_created_date from one of the other columns to get the time it took for a package to be delivered. I want to use the actual_delivery_date_if_known column if there is a value there and the artist_eta column if the value is null in the other column.

I initially tried setting up a for loop similar to this:

```
if data['actual_delivery_date_if_known].dropna():
    data['shipment_delivery_difference'] = data['actual_delivery_date_if_known'] - data['shipment_created_date']
else:
    data['shipment_delivery_difference'] = data['artist_eta'] - data['shipment_created_date']
```

That didn't work due to trying to use a series boolean in the if statement. So then I tried:

```
for i in data['actual_delivery_date_if_known].dropna():
    if i: 
        data['shipment_delivery_difference'] = data['artist_eta'] - data['shipment_created_date']
    else:
        data['shipment_delivery_difference'] = data['artist_eta'] - data['shipment_created_date']
```

Also didn't work. It didn't error, but just constantly updated everything to the else and it all came from the 'artist_eta' column.

Lastly, I tried replacing the NaT values in the 'actual_delivery_date_if_known' column with a random value that did not appear in the dataset.

```
data['actual_delivery_date_if_known'] = data['actual_delivery_date_if_known'].fillna('2000-01-01')

for i in data['actual_delivery_date_if_known']:
    if i != Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00'):
        data['delivery_shipment_difference'] = data['actual_delivery_date_if_known'] - data['shipment_created_date']
    else:
        data['delivery_shipment_difference'] = data['artist_eta'] - data['shipment_created_date']
```

But this is doing the same thing as the previous attempt and constantly updating with the else conditions.

Edit: Some dummy data

```
shipment_created_date  artist_eta   actual_delivery_date_if_known
---------------------|------------|-----------------------------
2021-06-30 23:09:04  | 2021-07-15 | NaT
2021-06-30 21:42:09  | 2021-07-26 | NaT
2021-06-30 21:40:04  | 2021-07-14 | NaT
2021-06-30 21:35:05  | 2021-07-05 | NaT
2021-06-30 21:12:56  | 2021-07-01 | 2021-07-10 12:17:15
```

Desired results would be:

```
delivery_shipment_difference
-----------------------------|
14 days 00:50:56
25 days 02:17:51
13 days 02:19:56
4 days 02:24:55
9 days 15:03:19 (this row is the only one that comes from the 'actual_delivery_date...' column)
```

Comment: Can you provide a dummy data, plus expected out come?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel just edited to add some

Comment: I got the results you are after with `combine_first`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your timestamps to Unix Epoch time, subtract and convert back.

If you have a dataframe I suggest youy use apply for each row and create a new column that you append your results to:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combine_first`.  It does exactly what you want.

```py
...
dataf["delivery_shipment_difference"] = (dataf["actual_delivery_date_if_known"].combine_first(dataf["artist_eta"]) - dataf["shipment_created_date"])
```

So `combine_first` plays the role of `SQL coalesce`. We update our value if the value is `None`

### complete 'runable' code and results

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
shipment_created_date|artist_eta|actual_delivery_date_if_known
2021-06-30 23:09:04|2021-07-15| 
2021-06-30 21:42:09|2021-07-26| 
2021-06-30 21:40:04|2021-07-14| 
2021-06-30 21:35:05|2021-07-05| 
2021-06-30 21:12:56|2021-07-01|2021-07-10 12:17:15"""), sep="|",)

# cast to datetime
dataf = dataf.transform(pd.to_datetime, errors="coerce")

print(dataf["actual_delivery_date_if_known"].combine_first(dataf["artist_eta"]) - dataf["shipment_created_date"])
```

[image]